# JAXB custom binding - Prefix must resolve to a namespace

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I'm trying to generate the java classes from a WSDL using the maven-jaxb2-plugin with no success. The WSDL contains two definitions for a complextype called stringArray, so I was trying to create a custom binding so the two classes don't collide while being created. The problem is that I keep getting this error:

`XPath: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Prefix must resolve to a namespace: wsdl`

My Maven maven-jaxb2-plugin plugin config is like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <generatePackage>com.arkdia.seus.service.stamping.xml.invoice.cancel.implementation.finkok</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                    <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/finkok/bindings</bindingDirectory>
                    <bindingIncludes>
                        <include>bind.xjb</include>
                    </bindingIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My bind.xjb has the following:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings
        node="/wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancel']/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancellation']">
        <jaxb:bindings
            node="/xs:complexType[@name='stringArray']">
            <jaxb:factoryMethod name="CancelStringArray" />
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

I tested the XPath using this [online tool](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), and it seems correct, but when I compile mi code with Maven I get the error I mentioned before.

What I am doing wrong?

Edit:

The WSDL definition is [here](https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl)

Thanks to @LMC I noted a namespace was missing ans updated mi bind.xjb to add it, but now I get this error:

`xpath evaluation of results in empty target node`

Edit 2:

Following @LMC suggestion I updated my bind.xjb file to include the schema location. But now even though I defined a new class name for teh conflictind complex types I get this error:

`two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class`

My new bind.xjb looks like this

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl"
        node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancellation']/xs:complexType[@name='stringArray']">
        <jaxb:class name="CancellationStringArray" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl"
        node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancel']/xs:complexType[@name='stringArray']">
        <jaxb:class name="CancelStringArray" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: There's no `wsdl` namepace defined in bind.xjb. Add the wsdl code to the question please.

Comment: @LMC I added a link to the WSDL

Comment: Try `<jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl" node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancellation']">` in the second binfings element.

Comment: It worked solving that problem. Now I am back to my original problem, how do I solve the collition?

Answer (score 0):

The last problem was because there was a third element with the same name, so the final bind.xjb was like this

```
<jaxb:bindings version="1.0"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl"
        node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancellation']/xs:complexType[@name='stringArray']">
        <jaxb:class name="CancellationStringArray" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
    <jaxb:bindings
        schemaLocation="https://demo-facturacion.finkok.com/servicios/soap/cancel.wsdl"
        node="/wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema[@targetNamespace='http://facturacion.finkok.com/cancellation']/xs:element[@name='stringArray']">
        <jaxb:class name="CancellationStringArrayElement" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Thanks to @LMC for the help identifying the missing namespace declarations and the missing schemaLocation in the jaxb:bindings